# Using Oracle bind variables in an application which only supports standard SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an application which works fine to execute and parse standard SQL queries, but not PL/SQL.

I'm trying to use bind variables, and because of lack of PL/SQL support I thought I could create a function that accepts a single variable, queries a DB, and returns the result.

My function is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BIND_FUNC 
(
  IN_FLOAT IN BINDING_TEST.C2_FLOAT%TYPE 
) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS 
  BINDTEST_CURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN BINDTEST_CURSOR FOR
  'SELECT * FROM BINDING_TEST WHERE C2_FLOAT = :IN_FLOAT' USING IN_FLOAT;
  RETURN BINDTEST_CURSOR;
END BIND_FUNC;
```

My problem is that I'm not sure how to make the return value appear to my application as a normal result set.

In SQL Developer if I run the query **SELECT BINDING_FUNC(1) FROM BINDING_TEST** I get a result like:

```
{<C1_VARCHAR2=This is some text,C2_FLOAT=1>,}
```

If I do something like below I get more along the results I'm looking for, but again the syntax doesn't appear supported in my application:

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  :cur := BIND_FUNC(1);
END;
/
PRINT cur;
```

Comment: Can you use a table collection expression, with a function that returns a pipelined table? (Not relevent to your question, but your function doesn't need to use dynamic SQL.)

Comment: I don't understand.  pl/sql is not a function of an application.  It runs in the database.  What is the application language/framework?

Comment: The SQL you probably want to execute is `SELECT BIND_FUNC(1) FROM DUAL`

Comment: @oldprogrammer given that the OP is trying to solve their problem with a function we can assume they know that PLSQL runs in the database. I think the problem is their application can't *call* PLSQL. Probably they're using a framework, you know the sort of thing: make simple tasks a matter of configuration, make everything else difficult if not impossible ;-)

Comment: @APC is right - It seems that I can't call PLSQL or that I can't handle PLSQL responses for some reason. To be honest I don't understand any of this and I'm just trying to read articles about this particular problem so it's been tricky. I found that I can parse the above response with xmltable in SQL Developer, but my own application doesn't seem to like that (returns ORA-00911). At this point I'm thinking it may just not be possible.

Comment: So please answer @oldprogrammer's question: what programming language or framework is your application written in?

Comment: @APC It uses libclntsh.dylib.12.1 from the "Basic" Instant Client package - but whatever bindings it has to that library don't seem to support the above.

Comment: An Oracle supplied library for connecting to Oracle databases is not the problem. Try again. Please understand, all we know about your situation is **what you tell us**. If you don't provide clear details there's not much we can do to help you.